# DAX measure to count duplicates with date filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking for a guidance on how to structure a DAX measure on PowerBI that can count duplicates and engage with date filter. Please see the detail as below

**My data sheet**

It contains the following items:

- Unique ID
- Email
- Country
- Webinar date
- Webinar name
- Registered (all data in the sheet are "Yes")
- Attended

**My goal**

I would like to understand the registration and attendance situation by each user and filter by Webinar date. For example, the user with "Unique ID 500" registered 5 different webinars so far but only attended 3 of them.

**DAX**

To achieve this goal, I would like to count the number of registration and the number of attendance by user. Therefore, I wrote the following DAX to create a new table and built the relationship between this new table and original table by "Many to Many" and "Dual direction".

```
Count of Unique ID = 
SUMMARIZE(
   Sheet0,
   Sheet0[Unique ID],
   Sheet0[Email],
   Sheet0[Country],

   "Number of registration"
   COUNT(Sheet0[Email])

   "Registered webinar"
   CONCATENATEX(Sheet0, Sheet0[Webinar name], ", "),

   "Number of attendance"
   CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet0[Email]), Sheet0[Attended] = "Yes"),

   "Attended webinar"
   CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(Sheet0, Sheet0[Webinar name], ", "), Sheet0[Attended] = "Yes")
)
```

**Issue**

It seems that something missing from DAX. I created a visual in accumulated graphs successfully with "Unique ID", "Number of registration" and  "Number of attendance" from new table. Then, I set "Webinar date" from original table as filter. It works correctly. I can verify the graphs by checking original data sheet manually.

However, when creating a visual in table with "Unique ID", "Number of registration" and  "Number of attendance" from new table and filtering the data by "Webinar date" from original table, it doesn't work. The table shows all data rather than filtered data.

It will be appreciated if someone can help me solve this issue.